# Vertex cover approximation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, graph

I believe this runs in \$O(V+E)\$ but I wouldn't be able to explain the reasons why. I was looking for some general code review and any help on understanding the runtime.

```
var Graph = function() {
    this.adj = {};
}

Graph.prototype.addEdge = function(v, w) {
    if (!Array.isArray(this.adj[v])) this.adj[v] = [];
    if (!Array.isArray(this.adj[w])) this.adj[w] = [];

    this.adj[v].push(w);
    this.adj[w].push(v);
}

var vertexCover = function(G) {
    var visited = {};
    var cover = [];

    var u;
    for (var v in G) {
        if (!visited[v]) {
            for (var i = 0; i < G[v].length; i++) {
                u = G[v][i];
                if (!visited[u]) {
                    visited[u] = true;
                    visited[v] = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (var x in visited) {
        cover.push(x);
    }
    return cover;
}

var ex = new Graph();
ex.addEdge(0, 1);
ex.addEdge(0, 2);
ex.addEdge(1, 3);
ex.addEdge(3, 4);
ex.addEdge(4, 5);
ex.addEdge(5, 6);
console.log('graph', ex.adj);

console.log(vertexCover(ex.adj));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand, your traversal is breadth first rather than depth first. And looking at that nested for loop, that's almost an squared operation if all your vertices are adjacent to all the others. But I'll leave the math to other reviewers, I'm terrible. :D

Anyways, code-wise, you went for the prototypal approach for `addEdge` but didn't do the same `vertexCover`. Why is that?

I'd also skip the OOP approach and just do an object with vertex names as key and arrays as values. `addEdge` and `vertexCover` will be standalone functions. OOP-ish JS is fine if you plan to do inheritance. In this case, you're not.

I also suggest you do `Object.keys` and array methods instead of `for-in`. Not that it's faster or anything. `for-in` will iterate through properties including ones on the prototype. The usual guard for that is a `hasOwnProperty` check. `Object.keys` only iterates through the instance properties plus it returns an array of them, allowing you to use array methods.

Additionally, if available, use ES6 syntax. The arrow functions go well with array methods, especially `map`. [The following](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjjOBr) is an example using ES6 syntax (which may not work yet in browsers, without transpilation).

```js
function createGraph(){
  return {};
}

function addEdge(graph, v1, v2){
  // This is simply inlining the check and push.
  (graph[v1] = graph[v1] || []).push(v2);
}

function vertexCover(graph){
  
  // For each vertex, we mark itself and its adjacent vertices
  var visited = Object.keys(graph).reduce((visited, vertex) => ({
    // Spread operator allows us to "merge". We merge the existing
    // visited object, we merge the one created from the adjacent
    // vertice, as well as itself.
    ...visited,
    ...graph[vertex].reduce((c, vertex) => (c[vertex] = true, c), {}),
    [vertex]: true
  }), {});

  // Since visited is an object, we convert it into an array.
  return Object.keys(visited).map(key => key);
}

var ex = createGraph();

addEdge(ex, 0, 1);
addEdge(ex, 0, 2);
addEdge(ex, 1, 3);
addEdge(ex, 3, 4);
addEdge(ex, 4, 5);
addEdge(ex, 5, 6);

console.log('graph', ex);
console.log('coverage', vertexCover(ex));
```

Answer (score 2):

As you can see after adding edges to the graph, G[v] has the list of neighbours of v, correct?
Therefore the length of G[v] for the vertex v is equal to the number of edges joining v.
Notice that each edge u-v appears twice in G, once in the neighborhood set of u, and once in the neighborhood of v (G[u] contains v and G[v] contains u both referring to the single edge u-v).
So these being said let's have a look at the code.

We iterate over all vertices in the outermost for loop;
for each vertex v in the set of vertices, we iterate over all edges connected to it.

Since each edge has appeared twice in the list (as mentioned above), we are basically counting (or visiting) each edge twice using these two nested loops.
Hence, the complexity of these two for loops could be O(E) where E is the number of edges in the graph.

Notice that the outer loop, iterates through all vertices any way. So, the complexity of the runtime cannot be less than O(V). This being said the complexity of the algorithm is the maximum of O(E) and O(V), which is exactly what O(V+E) means.

Comment: So the plus symbol means maximum?

Comment: Yes, if you check the definition of Big O, + effectively means whichever is bigger. To get an idea assume the example that the code complexity is provided as O(V+V^2). Since V^2 is bigger than V, it will be simplified as O(V^2), won't it?